# SPSS Likert Scale analysis

Tags: chi-squared-test, spss, likert

I have taken a survey of responses for different groups of students. Each question on the survey is in the form of a Likert scale response (1-7) I have decided to collapse this scale into a positive, neutral, negative response (ie. 1-3). I have done a chi-square test between two groups of students for individual questions but I am trying to figure out how to do a chi-square test between the same two groups of students for multiple questions. I.e. combining their responses for questions 1-5 and comparing this between student group 1 and student group 2...

Comment: Why mention SPSS here? Are you asking for SPSS guidance? If so, that would be off-topic here. Please see advice in the Help Center on software-specific questions.

Comment: what are your hypotheses ?

Comment: The survey has been reliability tested to make sure that it is acceptable to combine each group of the questions. In order to test whether there is a statistical different between the responses of the two student groups on each combined set of questions is it valid to find a mean of the group of questions for student group 1 and student group 2 and then do statistical t-test on these two samples?